# AngularJS dynamic pagination: how to limit the maximum visible buttons

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, pagination

After reading a lot of pagination plugins, i did not understand and created one in mongoose, angularjs, express, node stack manually
Now in my client code I have the total number of items in result **( results are fetched from server on every page change )** so they are dynamic and not fixed as there might be real time updates. So in my ui I am writing -

```
div.pagination-user.pull-right
                    a.page.gradient(ng-class="{disabled:currentPage == 0}",ng-click="prevPage()") Prev
                    a.page.gradient(ng-repeat="n in range(1,totalItems)",ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}",ng-click="setPage()",ng-bind="n",ng-show="Math.abs(currentPage-n)<3") 1
                    a.page.gradient(ng-class="{disabled:currentPage == pagedItems.length-1}",ng-click="nextPage()") Next
```

I tried the ng-show attribute to check if n the current index is near to the currentPage and ng-show if the condition is like that for both ends ( so instead of **(n-currentPage)** i used **Math.abs(currentPage-n)** )

I guess that is where i am going wrong, but if there is another way to limit the number of page buttons visible in the client code can anyone suggest that please

If in any case my controller's code affects this it is as follows -

```
angular.module('app').controller('PaginationDemoCtrl', function($scope,$filter, mvUser) {
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 2;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    var paginatedResults = function(page){
        var result = mvUser.query({page:page},function(res){
            $scope.maxSize = 5;
            $scope.totalItems = Math.ceil(res.count/$scope.itemsPerPage);
            $scope.currentPage = res.current;
            $scope.pagedItems = res.results;
        },function(err){
            console.log("some error");
        })
    };
    $scope.setPage = function () {
        $scope.currentPage = this.n;
        paginatedResults($scope.currentPage);
    };
    $scope.prevPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
            $scope.currentPage--;
            paginatedResults($scope.currentPage);
        }
    };
    $scope.range = function (start, end) {
        var ret = [];
        if (!end) {
            end = start;
            start = 0;
        }
        for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
            ret.push(i);
        }
        return ret;
    };

    $scope.nextPage = function () {
        if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.totalItems - 1) {
            $scope.currentPage++;
            paginatedResults($scope.currentPage);
        }
    };


    paginatedResults($scope.currentPage);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing pagination with #ngTasty ?
http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/